# Create a PODIO item with relationship with podio api for PHP

Tags: podio

How can we create an item and relate it to other items (setting the values on a relationship field)? I found no examples regarding those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just found how to do it.

1) Get the 'item_id' value for the app item you want to relate to in the parent application.

```
$item_id = $item->item_id;
```

2) Use the item_id on the child application relationship field.

```
new PodioAppItemField(array("external_id"  => "my_rel_field", "values" => array( 'item_id' => $item_id)))
```